# TCL Segmentation fault when loading a static library

Tags: c++, c, tcl, fault

I've creating a gRPC client server application in C++. The messages are defined in a protobuf file and the generated code is bundled with my own c++ commands and the gRPC libraries to create a static grpc_lib.a.
In turn this grpc_lib.a is linked to relevant client and server code to create  both a client and server application. This all works and the code runs.

Most of my test code is TCL based. Therefore, I created another static library (tcl_grpc.a) consisting of grpc_lib.a and c source code which details the TCL commands.
This is all standard stuff.
However, the problem is that I cannot load the tcl_grpc.a library into my TCL shell.
I constantly get a "segmentation fault"

Has anyone else come across similar problems when loading libraries into TCL?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: About all we can really say from the information you give is “something isn't working”. Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: That's a fair response and thank you for it.
Bizarrely, no stack trace was issued. The information is frustratingly spartan. This happens during the loading of the library.
My query is if anyone has experienced something similar when loading c++ libraries into TCL?
Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: When you load a library into Tcl (whether that's dynamically or statically), it's init function is called to allow the library to register the commands (and other things) it creates. Typically if the library is `libfoo.so` or `foo.dll` then the function is called `Foo_Init`. For static linked stuff, `Tcl_StaticLibrary` does the init function registration (and you `load` with an empty filename). But as the init functions are C code, they can go wrong in many ways; it's hard to say what the problem is without further info.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was incorrect mixing of c and c++ libraries.
It is not a fault with TCL
The created TCL library was .c files only which were calling c++ classes from  different libraries.
Solution was break the tcl lib into both .c and .cpp files, which were compiled separately using g and g++ respectively.
The cpp files will reference the classes from the cpp libraries.
Thanks for all the feedback